# App is compatible with Jelly bean tab on play store but incompatible with Kitkat tab

Tags: android, performance

I opened play store app on my tab has os jelly bean has option of downloading but another tab contain kitkat os saying app version is incompatible with this device. I am very confused. Image link of tab is this 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2wf2ucm72lwquc/IMAG1827%20%281%29.jpg?dl=0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tact.sec"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    >

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        />


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:required="false" />


    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_api" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TranslucentStatus">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".VoterSearch"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Dashboard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ULBVoter"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PrintSlip"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactUs"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutUs"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Circulars"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CircularPdf"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PhotoAlbum"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PhotoGallery"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MediaAlbum"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MediaGallery"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoGalleryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoPlayActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PRIVoterSearch"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PRIVoter"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PoliticalParty"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PriVoterSlip"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BLOROSOList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchBLOROSO"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PRIVotingResultSearch"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PRIVotingResult"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CommissionersDesk"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity android:name=".PRISingleResultCase" />

        <activity android:name=".PRIGPWardWinners" />

        <activity
            android:name=".GISMapMarker"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SearchPPollingCenterMap"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ImportantForms"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ULBPSummary"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PriStats"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Publications"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PollingPercentageGPPG"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PRIReservationResult"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PRIReservationSearch"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".WinnerList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".WinnerListShow"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".PressRelease"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".HorizontalBarChartActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ActAndRule"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ActAndRuleListShow"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MobileSelectULBStats"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ULBStats"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SingleNewsView"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".NewsList"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ElectionSymbol"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".DistrictPlanningCommitteeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SingleNewsPdf"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoadOrgnizationalStructure"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".DistrictOffice"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".DistrictOfficers"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Tenders"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


        <activity
            android:name=".SearchPPollingCenterULBMap"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".GISULBMapMarker"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


        <activity
            android:name=".NewsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"

            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="NewsActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        />


        <service android:name="fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the attached screenshot, it shows designed for phone, which means that it is supported by phone only.
Reason might be like the app does not make use of Honeycomb-specific features, which are included to support android tablets.

Comment: But mostly app is showing designed for phone but they are all have install option . But my app showing incompatable . I done research and put 
        android:required="false"  in every manifest permission .